# Date Modified returning long decimal number instead of a date, getmtime

Tags: python, date, format, os.path

I'm simply trying to return a legible date modified value for a file.

```
import os
from sys import argv
script, file = argv


path = "/Users/User/temp/" + file 


#print os.stat(path)

print os.path.getmtime(path)
```

Then in terminal I write --   python script.py file.py.

In both the os.stat and getmtime values, it's returning this weird value -- 1477712543.0.

What is this value and how do a get a legible value that makes sense, maybe in mm/dd/yyyy h:m:s format, which is what I thought I'd be getting...

Thanks much

Comment: Nevermind Got it.  Had to import time and add   time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(path)).  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you figured a different way out but it is important to say that the weird value is actually not a weird value 1477712543.0 that represents "a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch" more information can be found under:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Thanks